# Conditional Observable.forkJoin() building

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, reactivex

Based on the parameters of the function I want to build the forkJoin() method.

For example:

- if parameter1 is empty => don't put a http request for it inside the
  forkJoin()
- if parameter2 is empty => don't put a http request for it
  inside the forkJoin()

**Code:**

```
getAllByIds(parameter1: any, parameter2: any) {

    let itemList = new Array();

    return Observable.forkJoin(
         this.http.get('rest/fillin/ids/' + parameter1) // don't put this request for parameter1 if it is empty
         .map((res: Response) => res.json()),

         this.http.get('rest/textitem/ids/' + parameter2) // don't put this request for parameter2 if it is empty
         .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    ).map(
        data => {
            itemList.push(data[0]);
            itemList.push(data[1]);
            return itemList;
         }
     );
}
```

So, is it possible to build up the forkJoin() like this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually this depends on what do you expect to get when you skip some HTTP requests.

Should the output from `forkJoin()` contain `null` values or just ignore it completely?

```
function mockHTTPRequest(id) {
  return Observable.of(id).delay(100);
}

let parameter1 = 'a';
let parameter2 = false;

let sources = [];
if (parameter1) {
  sources.push(mockHTTPRequest('rest/fillin/ids/' + parameter1));
}
if (parameter2) {
  sources.push(mockHTTPRequest('rest/textitem/ids/' + parameter2));
}

Observable.forkJoin(...sources)
  .map(data => {
    console.log(data.length);
    return data;
  })
  .subscribe(values => console.log(values));
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/qorulel/5/edit?js,console

This solution just doesn't create source Observables if `parameter1` or `parameter2` is false. Notice, that `console.log(data.length)` can be from `0` to `2` depending on `parameterX` values.

Or you can just create `Observable.of(null)` instead of the HTTP requests.

```
function mockHTTPRequest(id) {
  return Observable.of(id).delay(100);
}

let parameter1 = 'a';
let parameter2 = false; 

let sources = [
  parameter1 ? mockHTTPRequest('rest/fillin/ids/' + parameter1) : Observable.of(null),
  parameter2 ? mockHTTPRequest('rest/textitem/ids/' + parameter2) : Observable.of(null)
];

Observable.forkJoin(...sources)
  .map(data => {
    console.log(data.length);
    return data;
  })
  .subscribe(values => console.log(values));
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/caheno/5/edit?js,console

Now the output has always 2 values. Just some of them are `null`.

Comment: I use the first solution. It works fine but when the `sources` array doesn't contain any elements then I get `EXCEPTION: _b is undefined` error. Is it because I don't make any empty checks on the `sources` array?

Comment: An empty array of sources shouldn't be a problem. This is in fact a valid usecase and is tested https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/observables/forkJoin-spec.ts#L199. Can you make a jsbin reproducing the problem?

Comment: I'm now sure that it is not releated with the empty request array. I'll look at to other places. Very useful comment;)

Comment: How to add a post http request for that sources array.